# lines of the same family of straight lines?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have three planes in $A^3(R)$ of equations $x-y+z=0$, $-x+3y-5z+2=0$ and $y-2z+1=0$. We have to determine if they belong to the same family of straight line.

If these three lines belong to the same family of straight lines there are two coefficient $\lambda$ and $\mu$ that
$$\lambda*(x-y+z)+\mu*(-x+3y-5z+2)=y-2z+1$$
or only one coefficient t that
$$(x-y+z)+t*(-x+3y-5z+2)=y-2z+1$$
Since there isn't a value for t that respect this equation, we can say that the three planes don't belong to the same family of stright lines.

Is it right?

At the first moment I tried to find the equation of the line.

Denoting with r the line of intersection of the $x-y+z=0$ and $-x+3y-5z+2=0$, the direction of r is determined by the homogeneous system

$$ \begin{cases}x-y+z=0\\-x+3y-5z=0\end{cases} $$

$l=\begin{vmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 3 & -5 \end{vmatrix}=2$, 
$m=-\begin{vmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -1 & -5 \end{vmatrix}=4$,
$n=\begin{vmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ -1 & 3 \end{vmatrix}=2$

the direction of r is given by $ \vec v_1=(2,4,2) $.

Denoting with s the line of intersection of the $-x+3y-5z+2=0$ and $y-2z+1=0$, the direction of s is determined by the homogeneous system

$$ \begin{cases}-x+3y-5z+2=0\\y-2z+1=0\end{cases} $$

$l=\begin{vmatrix} 3 & -5 \\ 1 & -2 \end{vmatrix}=-1$, 
$m=-\begin{vmatrix} -1 & -5 \\ 0 & -2 \end{vmatrix}=-2$,
$n=\begin{vmatrix} -1 & 3 \\ 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix}=-1$

the direction of s is given by $ \vec v_2=(-1,-2,-1) $ and is the same of r.

I need to find a point of r and a point of s to find the equations r and s and to see that they are different .

Is it possible to do this?
is there a method to find this points?